# Modify shader via Angle of Shadow

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

Simply put, I'm using two color ramps to add a texture X distance from the cartoon shadow and trying to subtract from the more horizontal parts of the shadow using True Normals as FAC, the result is fairly messy and I figure compositing might be a bit more controlled. This is in an attempt to mirror an art style, I need to be able to not use this noise texture at specific angles of the shadow and I really don't know how I'd be able to obtain this factor outside of normals, which have not worked particularly great so far.

Example:

[image]

Red = Texture, Black = Shadow - using 2.8 EEVEE

New Example: Trying to get sharper, more accurate results, rather than a blurry mess at some angles.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the texture to fill the white part or to follow the shadow edge?

Comment: The texture would only be visible at a specific angle within the white part (the red line = texture, as you can see it stops towards the upper-right). Using normals as FAC did not seem to work for this perfectly. I'll have to check on this again in Blender since it's been a few weeks.

Comment: Could you give an example of the art style?

Comment: The example is given in the picture directly above. Certain angles of shading are fuzz, other angles fuzzless.

Answer (score 7):

If you use the **Shader to RGB** node combined with *Greater Than* node. You can differentiate between light and shadow to create a cell-shading effect.

[image: cell-shading with Shader to RGB]

Simply add a texture to the original Diffuse BSDF, to texture the transition between light and shadow.

[image: material setup]

This is how the effect looks in motion.

[image: movement of the shadow]

You can sharpen or smoothen the shadows edge by decreasing the lamps energy, increasing its radius and lowering the threshold of the greather than node.

[image: shadow edge]

Comment: That is nothing short of freakin' awesome!!! Starring this question for later use :)